# Scrolling in any place of application should cause scrolling in last used combobox

Tags: c#, wpf, scroll, mousewheel

I want to add to my application, that when I use the mousewheel in any place of my application it should case a scrolling in the last active or last used combobox.

Can you help me? How should I proceed.

Thank you very much.

Comment: could you post a xaml or any code for a similar scenario? also point the scrolling issue in the code.

Comment: Hello pushpraj, thank you very much for your answer. I'm sorry but I don't have any code for a similar scenario. But maybe I can describe it a little bit more: When I've got a WPF Combobox. Then I can click on it and select a value. When I hover with my mouse over this combobox and use my mousewheel then the selection changes (as long as I'm using the mousewheel). This is a integrated standard functionality of WPF. Now I want activate this feature on any place of my application: not only on hover of this combobox. I hope this helps a bit.

Comment: If in understand you correctly then you want mouse wheel to work on the focused element regardless of the mouse is hovering it or not. Correct me if I am not inline with your idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two ways I attempted to solve the problem

**Approach 1: Attached properties**

I have created a class `MouseExtension` with an `Attached Property` `ScrollAnywhere` which will enable the bahavior on any element of your application. You may choose to have different scrollable region as well, so different combobox can be scrolled when mouse is in their respective regions. you may have a sub region which have this behavior for it's child control only. possibilities are unlimited.

Also this approach makes it injectable

example

```xml
<Window x:Class="CSharpWPF.View" 
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:l="clr-namespace:CSharpWPF"
        Title="MainWindow"
        l:MouseExtension.ScrollAnywhere="true">
    ...
</Window>
```

I have set the property `l:MouseExtension.ScrollAnywhere="true"` in order to enable the behavior

code

```cs
namespace CSharpWPF
{
    class MouseExtension : DependencyObject
    {
        public static bool GetScrollAnywhere(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (bool)obj.GetValue(ScrollAnywhereProperty);
        }

        public static void SetScrollAnywhere(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(ScrollAnywhereProperty, value);
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for ScrollAnywhere.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ScrollAnywhereProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("ScrollAnywhere", typeof(bool), typeof(MouseExtension), new PropertyMetadata(false, OnScrollAnywhere));

        private static void OnScrollAnywhere(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            UIElement element = d as UIElement;
            if ((bool)e.NewValue)
                element.PreviewMouseWheel += element_PreviewMouseWheel;
            else
                element.PreviewMouseWheel -= element_PreviewMouseWheel;
        }

        static void element_PreviewMouseWheel(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseWheelEventArgs e)
        {
            IInputElement element = FocusManager.GetFocusedElement(sender as DependencyObject);
            if (element != null && e.Source != element)
            {
                MouseWheelEventArgs args = new MouseWheelEventArgs(Mouse.PrimaryDevice, e.Timestamp, e.Delta) { RoutedEvent = UIElement.MouseWheelEvent };
                element.RaiseEvent(args);
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

this property is also settable via styles or programmatically

eg

```xml
<Style x:key="MyScrollStyle">
    <Setter Property="l:MouseExtension.ScrollAnywhere" Value="true"/>
</Style>
```

or

```cs
MouseExtension.SetScrollAnywhere(element, true);
```

or

```cs
element.SetValue(MouseExtension.ScrollAnywhereProperty, true);
```

---

**Approach 2: Override method**

this is rather simple approach if you can access the code behind of window or user control.

simply paste the code below in the class and rest will be handled

```cs
    protected override void OnMouseWheel(MouseWheelEventArgs e)
    {
        IInputElement element = FocusManager.GetFocusedElement(this);
        if (element != null && e.Source != element)
        {
            MouseWheelEventArgs args = new MouseWheelEventArgs(Mouse.PrimaryDevice, e.Timestamp, e.Delta) { RoutedEvent = UIElement.MouseWheelEvent };
            element.RaiseEvent(args);
            e.Handled = true;
        }
        base.OnMouseWheel(e);
    }
```

---

**Conclusion**

You may choose the method which you prefer. I would suggest to go for attached property approach as that make this behavior plug and play. E.g. You can turn on or off the behavior via a check box. You can store the user preference in settings and apply to the property.

Attached properties allows you to extend the behavior, may you need another behavior after this.

Comment: Wow pushpraj, thank you soooo much for your detailed answer! Your two approachs are so great. Thank you very very much. I've got one additional question: is it usual that when I've got two comboboxes and I use one of them (normal use, I click on it and select a value) then when I use the mousewheel out of this combobox => everything is working great. But when I use the second of these comboboxes (I click on it and select a value) and then out of this combobox I use my mousewheel: then both combobox values will be changed. Can I limit it so that only the last active combobox will be used?

Comment: it depends on which approach you use. if you use the attached property then do set it on common root of both combobox eg `<Grid l:MouseExtension.ScrollAnywhere="true">` or even `Window` like in example. Just set it once only, setting multiple time may have different behavior. I guess you have set it on two different user controls, if so then just move to main window only and it should be fine. Second Override method may only scroll last focused element. if you find it difficult then you may post a working sample of your code, I'll show how to set it correctly.

Comment: Thank you for your fast response. As recommended, I used your first apporach (attached property). I've set it in the Window tag.

See this code:

`<Window x:Class="Analyzer.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:my="clr-namespace:Analyzer"
        xmlns:l="clr-namespace:Analyzer"
        l:MouseExtension.ScrollAnywhere="true"
        Title="EAnalyzer" Height="820" Width="1400" MinHeight="820" MinWidth="1400" Background="WhiteSmoke" WindowState="Maximized">`

Comment: I haven't set it anywhere else. So I used this only once. The two comboboxes are in the same stackpanel **but** inside of a usercontrol. So I have a user control nested in my main window and the attached property is used in my main window. Should I use it only in every user control instead of the whole main window?

Comment: Could you send a sample of the application, may I have a look. You can set to multiple user controls if you need separate sub panel scrolling

Comment: Hello Pushpraj, sorry I was on vacation the last 10 days. But I thank you so much for your solution. I've added it again (as you told) and now everything is working fine.